# Retrieve the name of webapps deployed on Tomcat using JMX MBeans

Tags: tomcat, jmx, mbeans

Is it possible to determine what all webapps are deployed on a tomcat server using the mbean exposed?

Answer (score 0):

For Tomcat 7.0.x (you didn't say which version you're using).
Something like this ought to do the trick:

```
MBeanServer mbeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();

ObjectName on = new ObjectName("Catalina:j2eeType=WebModule,name=//*/*,J2EEApplication=*,J2EEServer=*");

Set<ObjectName> results = mbeanServer.queryNames(on, null);
```